How to dump a control group info?
Currently I am playing with cgroup-tools and I have found a lot of important tools to manipulate the control groups of the system. (I also know about many similar functionality in systemd, I intentionally looking for the original cgroup-tools and not the systemd part.)
However, what I would really like, is to have a tool which dumps all important data about a specific control group. I can not find that.
How can I see, for example, exactly what are the details of the cgroup called /system.slice/avahi-daemon.service? (Randomly picked cgroup name from an lscgroup output.)

It was much more simple as I tought. cgget can dump everything about a control group.
In the example, cgget /system.slice/avahi-daemon.service would be the command. Note, that has nothing to do to systemd. This whole control group, namespace etc. thing is entirely independent from systemd. That it is used mostly in systemd-related context, is only coincidence.
